# How to create temporal table from current and history?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbt

Let's say I have a current table that looks like this:

```
location   status     price
A          sold       3
```

and I have a history table that looks as such:

```
location   field     oldval_str   newval_str   oldvar_num   newval_num   created_at
A          status    closed       sold         null         null         2022-06-01
A          status    listed       closed       null         null         2022-05-01
A          status    null         listed       null         null         2022-04-01
A          price     null         null         null         1            2022-04-01
A          price     null         null         1            2            2022-05-01
A          price     null         null         2            3            2022-06-01
```

How can I build a temporal table such as the following in pure SQL?

```
location   status     price   created_at
A          listed     1       2022-04-01
A          closed     2       2022-05-01
A          sold       3       2022-06-01
```

I am using a PostgresDB is dialect helps!

I know I can do this in Python, I'm stuck on calling dynamically named columns using the field from history. Would like to find an all SQL solution. Any resources to point to?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried or you want us to write the solution for you ?

Comment: I have a working solution in Python using a bunch of Pandas... but I don't really know where to start with SQL here.. If you can point me to some resources, more than happy to give it a stab, but havent a hard time using the "field" column values to select a column in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like this

```
SELECT
    l.location,
    MAX(h.newval_str) FILTER (WHERE h.field = 'status') AS status,
    MAX(h.newval_num) FILTER (WHERE h.field = 'price') AS price,
    h.created_at
FROM locations l
LEFT JOIN history h ON h.location = l.location
GROUP BY l.location, h.created_at
ORDER BY h.created_at
```

Please, check a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0cefca4bf2c42e620efca0acc077154d)

Here the `locations` table is joined with the `history` table to get all of the available `location` rows, even those which values was not ever changed, and the `history` table does not contain any row about them.

If you do not need it, just use the `history` table alone.

```
 SELECT
    location,
    MAX(newval_str) FILTER (WHERE field = 'status') AS status,
    MAX(newval_num) FILTER (WHERE field = 'price') AS price,
    created_at
FROM history
GROUP BY location, created_at
ORDER BY created_at
```

Comment: There is no need for JOIN here. Everything OP needs is on the history table. This is a not so hard query that is why I asked OP if he tried anything. At least one simple select.... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ca6b13059b32f4a88b1785276f045bf5

Comment: `JOIN` is added to get all `location`s, even those,  which values was not changed and the `history` does not contain them. If OP does not want ALL locations, then `JOIN` is unnecessary, and you are wright in this case

Comment: Hi @Alexey, I am not talking about the OP and what he wants. I am talking about the example OP provided - there is only one location.

Comment: Yes, i missed it up

Comment: You did not, you answered the question, your answer is accepted and all is great. I am just pointing why op NEEDS to give more details and why this question is not good...